# Python.3 - np.where instead of For loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am using python-3.x and I want to find the column that has a standard division that greater than 0.5 and then I want to add one to each element in that column as you can see from the following code and it works **but instead of using for loob when I have a big array I want to use something like np.where or similar**

I tried to apply the np.where  but didn't work

```
np.where(np.std(population[:,i])>0.5, population+1, population+1)
```

here it work with the for loop:

```
import numpy as np
population = np.array(
              [[ 290,  -231,  399],
              [ 0,     181,   -226],
              [0,      0,     0],
              [0,      2000,  386],
              [0,      225,   2000]] )

for i in range (len(population.T)):       
    if np.std(population[:,i]))>0.5:
        population[:,i] = population[:,i] + 1       
    else:
        pass
```

Result:

```
 [[ 290   -230  400]
 [   0    182   -225]
 [   0    1     1]
 [   0    2001  387]
 [   0    226   2001]]
```

Comment: Simply do `population[:,np.std(population, axis=0)>0.5] += 1`.

Comment: thank you @Divakar , but the problem it will delete the column that didn't meet the condition, I want to keep all the column just modify the ones that met the condition how this can be done?

Comment: No, there's no deletion happening.

Comment: This did exactly what I want  `population[:,np.std(population, axis=0)>0.5] = population[:,np.std(population, axis=0)>0.5] + 1` if I add the `+=1` will say `invalid syntax` so I removed the `=` thank you @Divakar